# How to order columns and rows to create a relatively dense submatrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large matrix which comprises 1,2 and missing (coded as NA) values. The matrix has 500000 rows by 10000 columns. There are approximately 0.05% 1- or 2-values, and the remaining values are NA.

I would like to reorder the rows and columns of the matrix so that the top left corner of the matrix comprises a relatively high number of 1s and 2s compared to the rest of the matrix. In other words, I would like to create a relatively datarich subset of the matrix, by reordering the matrix rows and columns.

Is there an efficient method of achieving this in R?

In particular, I'm interested in solutions where sorting by the number of non-NA values in each row and column is not sufficient to produce a dense corner.

In addition, I'll add a constraint. The size of the dense corner will be pre-defined.

In the following example, the goal is to reorder the rows and columns so that the top leftmost 3x3 submatrix is relatively dense (i.e. few or no NA values).

`m1 <- matrix(c(rep(c(rep(NA, 3), rep(1, 7)), 1),
               rep(c(rep(2, 3), rep(NA, 7)), 7),
               rep(c(rep(NA, 3), rep(1, 7)), 2)
              ), nrow=10, byrow=TRUE)`

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [2,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [3,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [4,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [5,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [6,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [7,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [8,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[10,]   NA   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

The rows and columns are ordered by the number of non-NA values (using code from an answer below):

```
m1 <- m1[order(rowSums(is.na(m1))), order(colSums(is.na(m1)))]
```

However, this does not result in a dense 3x3 top leftmost corner:

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
    [1,]   NA   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
    [2,]   NA   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
    [3,]   NA   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
    [4,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [5,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [6,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [7,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [8,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [9,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
   [10,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

I thought that there maybe a set of optimisation procedures that I could implement as my working matrix is too large to do the reorganisation by eye.

Comment: There is no unique solution. You can reorder to have all 1s in your subset or all 2s or a mixture.

Comment: The solution can be unique or not unique. I am looking for a relatively dense submatrix (i.e. number of 1s or 2s/number of cells), or a submatrix of optimal density. In the example, the matrix could be reordered so that the top left most 3x3 submatrix comprised all 2-s (a density of 100%).

Comment: Sorry, but your question is still ill-defined. Clearly if all you care about is a 3x3 region, all you have to do is search (via kernel, perhaps) for any 3x3 region with zero or miminum `NA` values and "move" that collection of rows&columns to the top left.

Comment: Yes, a 'moving window' approach is one option I've been knocking around - and I think a good one. However, I thought it would be relatively inefficient on a large sparse matrix.